# I am trying to SSH to a server to perform some operations

Tags: python

I am new to Python.

I am trying to SSH to a server to perform some operations. However, before performing the operations, i need to load a profile, which takes 60-90 seconds. After loading the profile, is there a way to keep the SSH session open so that i can perform the operations later?

```
p = subprocess.Popen("ssh abc@xyz'./profile'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result = p.communicate()[0]
print result
return result
```

This loads the profile and exits. Is there a way to keep the above ssh session open and run some commands?

Comment: Don't start any new project in Python 2. It's outdated.

Comment: Althernately, the `paramiko` package is available in the stdlibs and there are bindings to ssh2 libs.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong if you have a `.profile` which takes over a minute to load.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct a **ssh command** like this `['ssh', '-T', 'host_user_name@host_address']` then follow below code.

##### Code:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

ssh_conn = ['ssh', '-T', 'host_user_name@host_address']

# if you have to add port then ssh_conn should be as following
# ssh_conn = ['ssh', '-T', 'host_user_name@host_address', '-p', 'port']

commands = """            
    cd Documents/
    ls -l
    cat test.txt
"""

with Popen(ssh_conn, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    output, error = p.communicate(commands)
    print(output)
    print(error)
    print(p.returncode)
```

##### Terminal Output:

[image]

**Please let me know if you need further explanations.**

> #### N.B: You can add command in commands string as many as you want.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Thanks. I will keep this in mind and take proper precaution while sharing